# Fixing the problem of Google translator output difference in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I load the site "translate.google.com" in the Web Browser control, it translates the word differently from the browser in normal mode.

(visual studio - windows form - c sharp)

. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Move to [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/), the WebBrowser Control (IE) is deprecated

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, my problem is solved. please put it in the answer section so that other people can use it.

Answer (score 1):

By using the control [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) the problem will be solved.

To use the control WebView2, `Microsoft.Web.WebView2` must be added to the project by nuget package manager :

[image]

Thanks to @Jimi who provided this solution.